# when up arrow key is pressed send text cursor to the end of the textbox focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently when you press the up arrow key in a textbox the cursor jumps to the beginning of the text. I'd like to override this feature and make it that when the up arrow key is pressed that is goes to the end of the text.

This is my code:

```
$("#searchBox").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 38) {
            searchBox.focus();
            $current.removeClass("searchBoxResultItem-active");
            searchBox.value = searchUserInput;
            searchBox.setSelectionRange(searchBox.length, searchBox.length);
        }
});
```

I was told that the above text would work, but I'm guessing since the arrow key is already set to take the code to the beginning it didn't work.

How can I override this feature?

Comment: why map the key differently? btw, e.preventDefault(); will probably do what you want to do

Comment: also $current isn't defined in scope so i'm not sure if that will work.....

Comment: @Daemedeor I have an unordered list that I want the user to be able to navigate through using arrow keys without it messing up the textbox focus position.

$current is just a variable I was using somewhere else.

Comment: @Katie - Why did you delete your lumber algorithm question?  I spent ah hour writing an answer to that question, and you simply deleted my work.  That's not very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `undefined` vars in your code. Simplifying a little bit your code, this is a working version:

```
$("#searchBox").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchBox.setSelectionRange(searchBox.value.length, searchBox.value.length);
    }
});
```

**[See JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnpbq2h7/)**

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted but those two lines did work. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the `strLenght` by 2 to ensure the cursor always ends up at the end, Opera sometimes sees a carriage return as 2 characters.

```
$("#searchBox").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 38) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $current.removeClass("searchBoxResultItem-active");

           // Multiply by 2 to ensure the cursor always ends up at the end;
           // Opera sometimes sees a carriage return as 2 characters.
           var strLength = $(this).val().length * 2;
           this.setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
        }
});
```

[**See JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnpbq2h7/2/)